# ubuntu private cloud - what happens to the changes I make on an instance

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, cloud

I'm just learning about Ubuntu Enterprise Clould. I installed it on a machine and I've installed a image.

If I create an instance from that image what happens to the changes I make to that instance?

The reason I'm asking this is because I wold like to keep the settings from that instance and run them on other other instances too. I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 3):

Starting an instance (with UEC) is like booting a computer for the first time, every time.  By default , with the UEC Cloud, when you shut down your instance the all modification to the instance itself is lost.

One way to keep the state of your instance would be to set the MANUAL_INSTANCES_CLEANUP variable to 1 (in the eucalyptus.conf file on the CC server).  This will prevent the system from deleting the instance files (image, kernel and ramdisk) on the NC.  You can than copy those files back to the CLC(or where you Walrus is) and upload them as your latest version.

Personally, I prefer to modify my images by running them with KVM at the command line.  This way everything I do is saved directly in the image.  I repeat this step until I'm happy with the image then I upload it on the CLC(Walrus).